# Android: Text extraction from PDF is terribly slow

Tags: android, itext

In my Android project I would like to extract plain text from a pdf file. I managed to do that, tried *itext* as well as *pdfbox* library. No matter which of them is used, the process of text extraction from one page pdf file takes 2-3 minutes(!). And this not a case of a simulator, but rather a Samsung Galaxy S7 running on Android 8.0.

I tried to explore in debugger what takes so long, however with Android Studio debugger I was not able to do that, sometimes the breakpoints dont work, call stack wasnt shown when program was paused, or the program terminates out of sudden after is paused...

The code is run in a JobIntentService:

```
public class GetMenuService extends JobIntentService {
...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new File(getFilesDir(), MENU_FILENAME).getPath());
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
                parsedText   = parsedText+ PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i+1).trim()+"\n"; //Extracting the content from the different pages
            }
            System.out.println(parsedText);
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
        }
        ...        
    }
}
```

To improve the performance it is needed to know what causes the problem. Is the library so slow? Is it missing any build optimization in Android Studio? Or is it because the code is inside of JobIntentService?

Comment: Did you try running the profiler on it? Under the Run menu select Profile. You should be able to find which thread is using all the CPU.

Comment: The code shown is itext, not pdfbox. What you should do remove the text extraction part - see how long it takes to just open the file. If that one is slow too, find out how long it takes to just read the bytes of the file.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for your replies. I investigated it some more and found out that the slowdown is related to fonts loading. Namely it is handler in itext library `private static class SetTextFont implements ContentOperator`. In my case, the pdf contains three fonts and creating each of them takes cca 50s. (There are some brutal loops with thousands of iterations) Since I am interested only in plain text, commenting out this handler could help, however i did not find the source code of android itext anywhere.

Comment: Can you share the PDF for analysis? This is awfully slow...

Comment: I am not sure what has changed, but I gave it another shot with PdfBox and now the parsing lasts cca 3s, which is fine for me.